# What's the best Apache MPM to serve static files only?

Tags: apache-2.2

What's the best Apache MPM to serve static files only? nginx and others are not an option.

event, worker, prefork or other?

If you can explain why as well, that would be awesome.

Comment: to the downvoter, can you please let me know what is wrong with my question?

Comment: And how is the question or answer "opinion based"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can use Apache 2.4, `event` is by far the fastest MPM: It behaves in a way similar to nginx, but still has most of Apache's advantages. [Apache has excellent documentation for it here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/event.html)

If you can only use Apache 2.2, the `worker` MPM is faster than prefork, with a lower memory footprint and more responsive to graceful restarts, and is highly recommended.

Apache 2.2 can also experimentally use event mpm, but there may be unpleasantness.

`Prefork` should really only be used if you need PHP or another non-thread-safe module, as it creates full processes for everything, and a decent number of HTTP 1.1 keep-alives will swamp your server heavily by not closing idle connections. Avoid.

Answer (score 0):

You can choose `event` for those Keep-Alive HTTP (not HTTPS) connections on Apache 2.x. remember this option is **experimental**.

I recommend using `worker`. it will provide a threaded module for your apache where it controls number of worker process, threads per worker, etc, which is ideal option for serving static content for large amount of concurrent requests.

`prefork` just provide multiple threadless processes where each TCP connection is handled by one process. it eats more RAM than that of `worker` under massive requests.